# .NET Core NuGet Package for Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

I am working on creating an API that fetches information about work items like Title, Iteration information etc from TFS. I installed the NuGet package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient for .NET Framework in a project and I was able to do this.

But, I would like to use a .NET Core project. When I went ahead and installed this in my .NET Core project, it shows up a yellow triangle in Dependencies as warning and I am not able to use the namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.WorkItemTracking.Client.

I want to know if Microsoft released a .NET Core replacement for this package. Or, is there any workaround to achieve what I am trying to do?

P.S - I tried doing this, https://mitchdenny.com/vsts-libraries-from-dotnet-core/, but that didn't seem to work either. Worst case scenario, I could go ahead using a .NET Framework project for now, but I wanted to look for alternatives first.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this easily is to use the API offered by TFS. To work with work items go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items