# Getting TFS work Item details in my ASP .net Core web API pro grammatically?

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core-webapi, tfs-workitem

I am creating one Application using ASP .NET Core In which when I am entering TFS work Item it I want to check the current status of that .

As I am beginner and I searched a lot but  I did not got any good documentation how I can achieve that , Please share some code snippet or documentation details if you have

Comment: I want to use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client  for that I have installed Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client but I am getting error that missing assembly referance ?

Comment: It seems you have duplicated thread and the issue has been solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526807/how-to-resolve-this-are-you-missing-assembly-reference?noredirect=1#comment105296949_59526807. You could accept an answer or add your own answer to close this thread.

Comment: Hi ashiwini patil, any update for this issue, did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You need to say what version of azure devops you are using.

The access can be made through WEB API or public client libraries

Some samples of access through libraries

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples

Answer (score 0):

TFS/DevOps provides [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to create, retrieve, update, or delete access to the service's resources.

For get work item tracking resources, you could refer to the API below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in your other similar question, some dependencies are **not available in .NET Core project**. Our SOAP object model found in our ExtendedClient NuGet package is quite older and only supported on windows desktop.

Take a look at this similar question: [.NET Core NuGet Package for Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299967/net-core-nuget-package-for-microsoft-teamfoundationserver-extendedclient)

In other words, you are not able to use `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` in .NET Core project.

Suggest you to use .NET Framework instead. Or you could also directly use [work items Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/Work%20Items?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). This should work properly with .NET Core project.