# How to resolve this?, are you missing assembly reference

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core-mvc, tfs-workitem

> The namespace client does not exist in Microsoft.teamfoundation  are you missing assembly reference

I have added Nuget packages `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` but I'm still facing this issue. I want to extract work item details from the TFS.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you going to use REST packages or soap packages? Could you share your code snippet？

Comment: actually that package does not work for .net core , Using another api that resolved my issue . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` provides access to version control, work item tracking, build, and more via public REST APIs.

`Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` works with and manages version control, work items, and build, and other resources from your client application. This package does not support Net Standard Client OM. This package should only be used in instances where our REST APIs don't offer the functionality you need (i.e. creating workspaces in TFVC).

If you use a TFS version >= TFS 2015, you should try to use the `REST API` to extract work item details. Regarding REST API version, you can refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops

Here is an existing sample code on the following link, you can refer to it:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs